# How to set form2's mdiParent to form1 c# winforms

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, mdiparent

I'm using two forms one mainform called 'Form1' and a seperate form called 'Form2'. So want to achieve something like that:

```
Form2.mdIparent = Form1;
```

But that didn't work. Can somebody help me ?  I'm using Windows, C# and WinForms.

Comment: `But that didn't work.` what exactly happened? How are you setting `mdiParent` for the first time? `Form` has `IsMdiContainer` property set to true?

Comment: `Form2` is called from `Form1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

from Form1

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e){  
   Form2 newMDIChild = new Form2();  

   newMDIChild.MdiParent = this; //where this means Form1

   newMDIChild.Show(); //if need to open Form2 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `Form2` has the property `IsMdiContainer` set to true.

Then, to define the caller Form being the parent of `Form2`, use `this` (the current instance of Form1) instead of the name of the form class :

```
Form2.mdIparent = this;
```